# How to conditionally make a DetailsView field read-only?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

Say I have a `DetailsView` with a bunch of fields, and I want only certain kinds of users to edit a few of them. They're too few to split them into another `DetailsView`, so what I'm thinking is to find some way to only allow a user to edit them based on some code-behind logic, effectively making them read-only at will.

I feel it's important to mention that the fields are both `TemplateField`s, not normal `BoundField`s with `ReadOnly` properties.

Any ideas? For some reason the required functions don't jump at me from reading the documentation.

Oh and I need eveyone to see their specific values, I just want to restrict edit access to them.

Comment: I wonder why this would get downvoted, it's not like it's spam or unclear or anything, or just asking for code (I provided it even when I figured it out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hrm apparently it was as simple as setting the `EditItemTemplate` property of the fields in question to `null`. Seems to be working fine so far!

Edit: A short code sample showing how I did it:

```
        foreach (DataControlField field in dvDRDetails.Fields)
            if (!fieldstoignore.Contains(field.HeaderText))
                if (field is TemplateField)
                    ((TemplateField)field).EditItemTemplate = null;
                else if (field is BoundField)
                    ((BoundField)field).ReadOnly = true;
```

Where `fieldstoignore` is an array of field headers that I always have set as editable. The rest fall in two categories: `TemplateField` that require the hack I discussed above and `BoundField` that have a `ReadOnly` property I can set.